# Partial Fourier series for $L^p$ functions, $p\ge 1$

Tags: fourier-series, lp-spaces, harmonic-analysis, holder-spaces

Let $f$ be an $L^2$ function on the unit circle $f \in L^2(S^1, d \theta)$. This is equivalent to giving a Fourier series $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} a_n e^{i n \theta}$ with $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} | a_n|^2 < \infty$. Then for every subset $S$ of $\mathbb{Z}$ the series $\sum_{n \in S} a_n e^{i n \theta}$ corresponds to an $L^2$ function $f_S$ on the circle.

Assume now that $f$ is continuous (or $L^p$ for some $p>2$ ($\,p\ge 1$ ?), or some Holder class, etc). Is the function $f_S$ again of the same class?

Observation: For smooth functions ( analytic functions) it's true, the Fourier coefficients are characterized as decreasing faster than any power of $|n|$  ( some exponential $q^{|n|}$, $|q|<1$) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a broad question with no definitive answer. You are asking for a description of characteristic functions $\chi_S$ that are [Fourier multipliers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplier_(Fourier_analysis)) bounded on $L^p$, or $C^\alpha$, etc.

Certainly, this is so when $S$ finite or $\mathbb{Z}\setminus S$ is finite. The best known nontrivial case is $S=\{n\in \mathbb{Z}:n\ge 0\}$ which is directly related to the [Hilbert transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform#Boundedness). Thanks to M. Riesz, we know that $\chi_S$ is a multiplier on $L^p$ for $1<p<\infty$. It's not a multiplier on $L^1$ or $L^\infty$, or on $C(\mathbb{T})$. It is a multiplier on $C^\alpha$ for $\alpha\in(0,1)$, however. None of these results are trivial.

Suggested reading: [An Introduction to the Theory of Multipliers](https://books.google.com/books/about/An_Introduction_to_the_Theory_of_Multipl.html?id=hxTamQEACAAJ&hl=en) by  Ronald Larsen, and  the references to the Wikipedia article on Fourier multipliers.

Comment: Oh, great answer, thank you!  I was interested in producing a bunch of boundary values of bounded holomorphic functions on the unit disk in a cheap way, hence the interest in the $L^{\infty}$ case.