# Is the positive part of the Fourier series of every continuous function , the Fourier series of some other continuous function?

Tags: continuity, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Let $f \in C[-\pi , \pi]$ , let $\hat f (n) : = \dfrac 1{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi f(t)e^{-int} dt , \forall  n \in \mathbb Z$ . Does there exist a continuous function $g : [-\pi , \pi] \to \mathbb C$ such that $\sum _{n=1}^\infty \hat f (n) e^{inx} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \hat g (n)e^{inx} , \forall x \in [-\pi , \pi]$ ?

Comment: Check out https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1291999/partial-fourier-series-for-lp-functions-p-ge-1 and the answer there. So, not in general.

Comment: @orangeskid : Ok I understand ... but is there any elementary proof of this negative answer or any elementary counter-example ?

Comment: Look at the Taylor series of $-\log (1-z)$ and deduce the Fourier series of $f_r(t) = -\log(1-re^{it})$